# Matrix Multiplication Implementation in CUDA C++ API with and without shared memory

Tags: c++, performance, beginner, matrix, cuda

Here is my implementation of matrix multiplication using the CUDA C++ API.
I tried to separate the source code into multiple files for easier maintenance and readability.

#### matrix.hpp

By creating this struct I wanted to keep things tidy and avoid passing a lot of parameters to functions and kernels later.

```
#pragma once

struct matrix {
    matrix(int rows, int cols) {
        this->rows = rows;
        this->cols = cols;
        this->size = rows * cols;
    }
    double *elements;
    int rows;
    int cols;
    int size;
};
```

#### kernels.cuh

Here I have placed the kernel prototypes. I wrote 2 versions of the matrix multiplication. One that makes use of shared memory and one that does not.

```
#pragma once

#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include "matrix.hpp"

#if SHARED == 1
    __global__ void matrix_multiplication_kernel(matrix a, matrix b, matrix c, unsigned int tile_size);
#elif SHARED == 0
    __global__ void matrix_multiplication_kernel(matrix a, matrix b, matrix c);
#endif
```

#### kernels.cu

Here is the actual implementations of the kernels.

```
#include "kernels.cuh"

#if SHARED == 1
__global__ void matrix_multiplication_kernel(matrix a, matrix b, matrix c, unsigned int tile_size) {
    int bx = blockIdx.x;
    int by = blockIdx.y;

    int tx = threadIdx.x;
    int ty = threadIdx.y;

    int row = by * blockDim.y + ty;
    int col = bx * blockDim.x + tx;

    extern __shared__ double buffer[];
    double *a_shared = &buffer[0];
    double *b_shared = &buffer[tile_size * tile_size];

    double sum = 0;

    for (int k = 0; k < (tile_size + a.cols - 1) / tile_size; k++) {
        if (k * tile_size + tx < a.cols && row < a.rows) {
            a_shared[ty * tile_size + tx] = a.elements[row * a.cols + (k * tile_size + tx)];
        } else {
            a_shared[ty * tile_size + tx] = 0.0;
        }
        if (k * tile_size + ty < b.rows && col < b.cols) {
            b_shared[ty * tile_size + tx] = b.elements[(k * tile_size + ty) * b.cols + col];
        } else {
            b_shared[ty * tile_size + tx] = 0.0;
        }
        __syncthreads();
#pragma unroll
        for (int n = 0; n < tile_size; ++n) {
            sum += a_shared[ty * tile_size + n] * b_shared[n * tile_size + tx];
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }
    if (row < c.rows && col < c.cols) {
        c.elements[row * c.cols + col] = sum;
    }
}
#elif SHARED == 0
__global__ void matrix_multiplication_kernel(matrix a, matrix b, matrix c) {
    int bx = blockIdx.x;
    int by = blockIdx.y;

    int tx = threadIdx.x;
    int ty = threadIdx.y;

    int row = by * blockDim.y + ty;
    int col = bx * blockDim.x + tx;

    if (row < c.rows && col < c.cols) {
        double sum = 0;
#pragma unroll
        for (int k = 0; k < a.cols && k < b.rows; k++) {
            sum += a.elements[row * a.cols + k] * b.elements[k * b.cols + col];
        }
        c.elements[row * c.cols + col] = sum;
    }
}
#endif
```

#### wrappers.cu

I created some `wrapper functions` in this file in order to keep my `main` function clean and offer some kind of high-level abstraction to the user.

```
#include "wrappers.cuh"
#include <iostream>

void matrix_multiplication(matrix a, matrix b, matrix c, unsigned int block_size) {
    cudaError_t error;
    dim3 dimBlock;
    dim3 dimGrid;
    dimBlock.x = block_size;
    dimBlock.y = block_size;
    dimBlock.z = 1;
    dimGrid.x = (c.cols - 1) / dimBlock.x + 1;
    dimGrid.y = (c.rows - 1) / dimBlock.y + 1;
    dimGrid.z = 1;

    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);
    float milliseconds = 0;

    cudaEventRecord(start);
#if SHARED == 1
    unsigned int tile_size = block_size;
    matrix_multiplication_kernel <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, 2 * tile_size * tile_size * sizeof(double)>>> (a, b, c, tile_size);
#elif SHARED == 0
    matrix_multiplication_kernel <<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>> (a, b, c);
#endif
    cudaEventRecord(stop);

    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);

    cudaEventElapsedTime(&milliseconds, start, stop);
    std::cout << "kernel execution time" << " " << milliseconds << " " << "ms" << std::endl;

    error = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (error != cudaSuccess) {
        std::cerr << cudaGetErrorString(error) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

#### wrappers.cuh

Here are the prototypes of the `wrapper functions`.

```
#pragma once

#include "kernels.cuh"

void matrix_multiplication(matrix a, matrix b, matrix c, unsigned int block_size);
```

#### main.cpp

Here is the `main` function.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include "wrappers.cuh"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void print(matrix m, std::string label) {
    std::cout << label << "[" << m.rows << "x" << m.cols << "] = " << std::endl;
    for (int row = 0; row < m.rows; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < m.cols; col++) {
            std::cout << m.elements[row * m.cols + col] << "\t";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 8) {
        std::cout << "NAME" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\t" << "matrix-multiplication" << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    int nDevices;
    cudaGetDeviceCount(&nDevices);
    for (int i = 0; i < nDevices; i++) {
        cudaDeviceProp prop;
        cudaGetDeviceProperties(&prop, i);
        std::cout << "GPU #" << prop.pciDeviceID << " " << prop.name;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    int a_rows = std::stoi(argv[1]);
    int a_cols = std::stoi(argv[2]);

    int b_rows = std::stoi(argv[3]);
    int b_cols = std::stoi(argv[4]);

    int c_rows = std::stoi(argv[5]);
    int c_cols = std::stoi(argv[6]);

    int block_size = std::stoi(argv[7]);

    matrix a(a_rows, a_cols);
    matrix b(b_rows, b_cols);
    matrix c(c_rows, c_cols);

    cudaMallocManaged(&a.elements, a.size * sizeof(double));
    cudaMallocManaged(&b.elements, b.size * sizeof(double));
    cudaMallocManaged(&c.elements, c.size * sizeof(double));

    fill_col(a, block_size); // Implementation not shown here
    fill_row(b, block_size); // Implementation not shown here

    matrix_multiplication(a, b, c, block_size);

    print(a, "a");
    print(b, "b");
    print(c, "c");

    cudaFree(a.elements);
    cudaFree(b.elements);
    cudaFree(c.elements);

    return 0;
}
```

So ... what do you think? Does it look good? Do you have any suggestions to make?

Comment: Where do you actually allocate `elements`?

Comment: @Zeta I guess you need the main ... I will include it but I will leave some functions out for simplicity. Those are for initialization of data and printing data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
matrix(int rows, int cols) {
    this->rows = rows;
    this->cols = cols;
    this->size = rows * cols;
}
```

0_0

Did you actually mean

```
matrix(int rows, int cols): rows(rows), cols(cols), size(rows * cols) {}
```

?

(Additionally beware of integer overflow; size_t would be better here.)

```
cudaMallocManaged(&a.elements, a.size * sizeof(double));
```

Managing object's resources in external calls is generally not a good idea. Two things can be done here:

1. `cudaMallocManaged` called from inside the `matrix`'s constructor.
2. Consequently, `cudaFree` could be called from `matrix`'s destructor, but—a better (IMHO) solution is to turn `elements` into a `unique_ptr` and call `cudaFree` from `elements`' deleter. Aside from raising consistency, this makes your `matrix` DefaultMoveable.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what bipll noted, the `elements` member is not initialized by the constructor, but left in a garbage state.  At the very least, make it `nullptr` with an inline data member initializer.

And it doesn’t have a destructor.  Shouldn’t it free the memory?  I think you really want a `unique_ptr` with a custom deleter.

The compiler generated assignment and copy members for you, but they will do the wrong thing.  You should mark them `=delete` to disable that.